# Open local html pages using http to test

Tags: javascript, html, xml, http, xmlhttprequest

I am coding a webapp and i get this kind of errors with chrome :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:\Users\Tordah\Desktop\foobar.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. 

&

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
```

I believe i get this error because the HTML file is accessed with *file:* protocol and not *http:* protocol which creates compatibility issues with XMLHttpRequest (That's a guess). I would like to know if there's any ways of testing my pages using http protocol only with my local machine (because only later in this project i will have access to a server, and therefore the app will only work using http, but for now i would like to be able to test it properly).

Is there any workarrounds that i could do on a local machine and that could with with the three browsers **IE, Firefox and Chrome?**

Thanks.

Comment: [**Wampserver**](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: have you tried xampp??
https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: I would consider running your own server locally like @adeneo suggested.

Comment: basically, you need to host your files over HTTP by running a server and then using `http://localhost` instead of `file:///`

Comment: Thanky you all this is perfectly what i was missing. Have a good day everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you didn't install a local server...i suggest you XAMPP, is the best for doing this kind of stuffs...

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

here is the url where you can download it. when you already install it, you have to copy your work into the directory

C:/xampp/htdocs/(here you paste your work)

open your browser and write in the url like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/(name of your work directory)/(what archive you want to see, better if it has index)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is flawlessly what i need. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a web server.  You have a bunch of different choices, but since you didn't mention an operating system, I'll suggest XAMPP from https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

That will give you an Apache distribution containing MySQL, PHP, and Perl and will run on Windows/Mac/Linux

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment and info, very interesting.